# How to use a refresh token for a different client

Tags: oauth, keycloak

We have a number of applications that currently do not use refresh tokens. Currently we have access tokens that last a long time. We know this is bad and I want us to move forward towards switching to longer lived refresh tokens with short life access tokens.

However, we are running into the problem of how the current expectation of how our applications work. The access token is stored in a cookie, and the different apps are all subdomains and share this access token. So if I logged in once to app A and then go to App B, I don't have to log in again.

This is proving problematic for refresh tokens, as they are scoped to an individual client. If I log into app A(which gets an access token and refresh token) and then go to App B, app B will fail to use that refresh token as the client/azp specified on it does not match the client that app B uses. We will get an error: "Invalid refresh token. Token client and authorized client don't match."

Is there a way to share refresh tokens between different clients? Or for me to get a new refresh token for the correct client without the user logging in again?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using confidential clients for your apps, you might want to have a look at the token-exchange feature of keycloak. In theory it should allow you to exchange the refresh token of app A for an access token targeted to app B.

What also might work would be a kind of Backend for Frontend (BFF) approach, where a service shared between the apps acts as an intermediary between the applications and keycloak. The service then stores the refresh and access token and issues an encrypted cookie to the application. Using this encrypted cookie the applications are able to make authenticated requests through the BFF to any resource servers.

Read more about Token Exchange here: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_token-exchange

Read more about BFF here: https://auth0.com/blog/backend-for-frontend-pattern-with-auth0-and-dotnet/

Answer (score 0):

> So if I logged in once to app A and then go to App B, I don't have to log in again.

It's not what access tokens are for. The access token allows an application to call external resources (an API). It's not connected to the user's session (e.g. an access token has its own expiration time, it can live longer or shorter than the user's session).

What you're after is Single Sign On (or just "user session"). Your authorization server (the service that issues access tokens) should establish a cookie-based HTTP session with the browser. Every time the user goes to a different application and needs to log in, they are redirected to the authorization server. The server can pick up the session from the cookie and issue a new access token for the given application without the need to authenticate the user. In this scenario, every application has its own access token and can refresh it when needed.